# how to reset the tf.estimator.Estimator parameters?

Tags: tensorflow

I tried tf.Graph() but can't get the variable to reset by new. The code is below:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
    clf_ = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=my_w2d.model_fn_wide2deep, params=param, model_dir="/Users/zhouliaoming/data/credit_dnn/model_retrain/rm_gene_v2_sall/")
    with tf.name_scope("rewrite"):
        clf2 = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=my_w2d.model_fn_wide2deep, params=param, model_dir="/Users/zhouliaoming/data/credit_dnn/model_retrain/genev2_s0/")
    out_bias = tf.get_variable("output_0/bias")
    out_b_rew = tf.get_variable("rewrite/output_0/bias")
    vars_ = clf_.get_variable_names()   ## only has clf_.get_variable_values()
    print("vars: %r\n output_0/bias: %r\ntrain-vars: %r" % (vars_, clf_.get_variable_value('output_0/bias'), tf.contrib.framework.get_trainable_variables()))
    print("before rewrite: out_bias: %r, out_b_rew: %r" % (out_bias.eval(), out_b_rew.eval()))
    out_b_rew.assing(out_bias)
    print("after rewrite: out_bias: %r, out_b_rew: %r" % (out_bias.eval(), out_b_rew.eval()))
```

and it just return error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tf_utils.py", line 31, in <module>
    out_bias = tf.get_variable("output_0/bias")
  File "/Users/zhouliaoming/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1262, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/Users/zhouliaoming/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1097, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/Users/zhouliaoming/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 435, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/Users/zhouliaoming/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 404, in _true_getter
    use_resource=use_resource, constraint=constraint)
  File "/Users/zhouliaoming/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 764, in _get_single_variable
    "but instead was %s." % (name, shape))
ValueError: Shape of a new variable (output_0/bias) must be fully defined, but instead was <unknown>.
```

=============== old infomation cut line =========

I defined a tf.estimator.Estimator model A by model_fn handler. 
I want to change model A's parameter by same old model's parameters as ckpt file.
I try to get model A's graph and then get the parameter's variable in Graph and then assigned it by my old model's  parameter.
Hope some advices! 
Thanks very much!

Comment: I wrote a generic answer since you question does not have many details. If you want more concrete advice, I would suggest trying some approach first. If you get stuck on something, ask that specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this, depending on exactly what you have available. For example, if you have the code and checkpoints from both models, you can create two separate graphs (`with tf.Graph() as g`) load the two checkpoints into them, read the variable values from one graph and assign it to a variable in another graph.

If you know exactly the variable you want to read in one checkpoint, you can restore just it (`Saver.restore` takes a list of variables to restore), or you can read it using tools like `CheckpointReader`

Comment: thanks very much! I have a try by tf.Graph(), but it sees not work. Is my code show do some changes? Hopw you advices.  I also want to try SessionRunHook, but havn't found suitable code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. The error in your question should be pretty descriptive. You are calling `get_variable()` with a name that does not match any existing variables. So, it tries to create a new one. For this, it needs to know the shape of the variable, but you did not specify it.

Comment: Thanks @iga for give me advices. Those days I tried the SessionRunHook but it has some mistakes. May I ask you this quertitions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535003/how-to-use-tf-train-saver-in-sessionrunhook? Thanks again.

Comment: I posted an answer there. Hope it helps. Also, when somebody answers your question, it is good to accept it.