# How to rewrite a tensorflow's checkpoint files?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to change a ckpt files's tensor's value by many other ckpt files's tensors, and use the modified ckpt files to restart TF  training jobs. 
Hope you some advices!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are standalone utilities for reading checkpoint files (search for `CheckpointReader` or `NewCheckpointReader`) but not modifying them. The easiest approach is probably to load the checkpoint into your model, assign a new value to the variable you want to change, and save this new checkpoint.

Comment: thanks! I actually want to modify a self-defined(by model_fu() ) estimator model by some other model's ckpt parameters, But I haven't found any way to modify  estimator's parameter. The question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541940/how-to-reset-the-tf-estimator-estimator-parameters

Comment: I responded to this other question. I don't quite understand what you mean by "modify estimator's parameter"? Estimator by itself does not really have any variables. It just combines other TensorFlow facilities to make it easy to do common things. If you are referring to some variables, all variables can be saved/restored as well as assigned and read the same way. I don't know anything special about estimators.