# How to use tf.train.Saver in SessionRunHook?

Tags: tensorflow

I have trained many sub-models, each sub-models is a part of the last model. And then I want to use those pretrained sub models to initial the last model's parameters. I try to use SessionRunHook to load other ckpt file's model parameters to initial the last model's.
I tried the follow code but failed. Hope some advices. Thanks! 
The error info is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_high_api_local.py", line 282, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/Users/zhouliaoming/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 124, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "train_high_api_local.py", line 266, in main
    clf_.train(input_fn=lambda: read_file([tables[0]], epochs_per_eval), steps=None, hooks=[hook_test])     # input yield: x, y
  File "/Users/zhouliaoming/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 314, in train
  .......
  File "/Users/zhouliaoming/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 674, in create_session
    hook.after_create_session(self.tf_sess, self.coord)
  File "train_high_api_local.py", line 102, in after_create_session
    saver = tf.train.Saver([ti])    # TODO: ERROR INFO:  Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.
  .......
  File "/Users/zhouliaoming/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3135, in create_op
    self._check_not_finalized()
  File "/Users/zhouliaoming/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2788, in _check_not_finalized
    raise RuntimeError("Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.")
RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.
```

and the code detail is:

```
class SetTensor(session_run_hook.SessionRunHook):
    """ like tf.train.LoggingTensorHook  """        
    def after_create_session(self, session, coord):
        """ Called when new TensorFlow session is created: graph is finalized and ops can no longer be added.  """
        graph = tf.get_default_graph()
        ti = graph.get_tensor_by_name("h_1_15/bias:0")
        with session.as_default():
            with tf.name_scope("rewrite"):
                saver = tf.train.Saver([ti])    # TODO: ERROR INFO:  Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.
                saver.restore(session, "/Users/zhouliaoming/data/credit_dnn/model_retrain/rm_gene_v2_sall/model.ckpt-2102")
        pass        

def main(unused_argv):
    """ train """
    norm_all_func = lambda x:  tf.cond(x>1, lambda: tf.log(x), lambda: tf.identity(x))
    feature_columns=[[tf.feature_column.numeric_column(COLUMNS[i], shape=fi, normalizer_fn=lambda x: tf.py_func(weight_norm2, [x], tf.float32) )] for i, fi in enumerate(FEA_DIM)]  # normlized: running OK!
    ## use self-defined model
    param = {"learning_rate": 0.0001, "feature_columns": feature_columns, "isanalysis": FLAGS.isanalysis, "isall": False}
    clf_ = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn_wide2deep, params=param, model_dir=ckpt_dir)
    hook_test = SetTensor(["h_1_15/bias", "h_1_15/kernel"])
    epochs_per_eval = 1
    for n in range(int(FLAGS.num_epochs/epochs_per_eval)):
        # train num_epochs
        clf_.train(input_fn=lambda: read_file([tables[0]], epochs_per_eval), steps=None, hooks=[hook_test])     # input yield: x, y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SessionRunHook is not meant for this use case. As the error says, you cannot change the graph once `sess.run()` has been invoked.

You can assign variables using `saver.restore()` in your "normal code". You don't have to be inside any hooks.

Also, if you want to restore many variables and can match them to their names and shapes in a checkpoint, you might want to take a look at https://gist.github.com/iganichev/d2d8a0b1abc6b15d4a07de83171163d4. It shows some example code to restore a subset of variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
class SaveAtEnd(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
  def begin(self):
    self._saver = # create your saver

  def end(self, session):
    self._saver.save(session, ...)
```